# How to route one URL to different controller/action with json data in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing server end of a JavaScript app. But engineer who write js and design APIs of this app decided all of ajax send json data to "one" URL, like this:

```
{
 "id":"...",
 "method":"method_name",
 "params":{...}
}
```

So, I must provide different service for different "method_name". And the Rails router can not  address this problem.

I can use the `Object.send` method routes the different service to different method, but, I want to distribute my code to different Controller class.

Can I parse the json data in `route.rb` file? Then route the `/url/method_name` to `controller/action` ?

Comment: IMHO, I think that the engineer who wrote this API should post the every method to every different service that you make. It will be easier to mantain and find possible errors.

Comment: Or you can ask him to send it to some "master" url and this url-method redirect that request, based on method name on Json, to the correct method.

Comment: Unfortunately, the JavaScript app is done.

Comment: So, you should take the second option.